# Getting Ubuntu on SSH Client on Macbook

Tags: ssh, gui, macbook

I have managed to install Ubuntu on my VPS with Kamatera (hosting company) today. I am using it to run some marketing software remotely as it was taking up resources on my Mac.

The issue comes when I open a remote console it shuts down after 20 mins or so, which is useless. However, I can load the Ubuntu GUI and desktop fine, but only for 20 mins.

I spoke to tech support and they said it will always reset like this and to download an SSH Client, I downloaded PortX.

I have managed to log into the server but it is a Terminal window and I don't know how to get Ubuntu back up and actually use the VPS.

Could somebody please help a Unix novice?

What I have tried in PortX:

[image]

Comment: If your goal is to use the GUI, then [this answer will point you in the right direction](https://askubuntu.com/a/1319421/1222991) to set up a Remote Desktop over SSH 

Comment: Hosting companies usually only offer Ubuntu server (no GUI), I don't know whats your `marketing software` is but running full-fledged desktop on server specs is a horrible idea, I have tried that once and it perform quite bad compared to consumer specs. I suggest if you want to fire up GUI, then you can choose a hosting service that provide system specifically designed for GUI use. Just throwing in my 2 cents

Comment: I got the XRDP installed and I have GUI up and running now. The marketing software is pretty low spec stuff, basically a web browser that scrolls linkedin. It is just a pain in the butt when I am trying to us it on my laptop.

Comment: The Linkedin Software runs perfectly on the new Ionos server and is exactly what I needed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Update - I moved to Ionos as it allows me to use a KVM connection indefinitely and it doesn't shut down. Much easier and saves me having to understand Linux :-)

Thanks for all of you help.

Comment: No further details required as the issue was solved by moving to a different hosting company